# Meteor redirect a user to uri after POST function returns data

Tags: node.js, url, redirect, meteor, uri

I have a post function that returns an oauth_token within the body.

I store this oauth_token value and append it to complete the uri.

How can I then redirect the user to the uri after I've received the body from the post request?

I am using npm package 'request'

Server.js

```
Meteor.methods({
 getGoodreads: function () { 
 var oauth = {
    consumer_key: 'mykey',
    consumer_secret: 'secretkey'
    };

 var url = 'http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/request_token'

 request.post({url:url, oauth:oauth, json:true}, function (e, r, body)  {
    req_data = querystring.parse(body);
    token = querystring.stringify({oauth_token: req_data.oauth_token});


  var uri = 'http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/authorize?'+ token; // trying to direct user to this uri

  });
 }
});
```

client.js

```
Template.profiles.events({
'click #goodreads': function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     Meteor.call('getGoodreads', function (error, result) {
       if (error) {
          console.log(error)
          } else {
         Router.go(result); //if I can get the uri value back here then I direct the user to the uri here
          }
      });
     }
});
```

After I've received the body, I therefore have the oauth_token which is appended to the uri as seen above. 
How do I then direct the user to this uri? I am not 100% familiar in setting up a callback function which seems like this is the method to use because the POST function is initiated when the user clicks a button on the page. So I only need to direct the user if this post function runs as the uri is dependant on the oauth_token.

Comment: What is `app`?  The answer to this depends on what `req`, `res` are, which is  defined by `app`.

Comment: good question, I assumed it was some native function when getting advised by Петър Петров. I have not created the app object. I will delete it.

Comment: So how is are you accepting requests from the user?  Or have you not gotten that far?  May want to look at `express`.

Comment: The user click on a button "goodreads" and invokes the whole authentication process. I think I need to pass the uri value to the client where I can use the iron:router function Router.go(uri) when the value is returned.

My framework is meteor.js

Comment: Oh, I missed that tag.  I don't know anything about `meteor`, but at this point it looks like you have enough information there to get a good answer.  Good luck!

Comment: I just came across this question and realized it's exactly what I'm trying to do now too (to the goodreads down) did you ever get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have, as example

```js
app.request('/', function(req,res){

var oauth = {
    consumer_key: 'mykey',
    consumer_secret: 'secretkey'
    };

var url = 'http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/'

request.post({url:url, oauth:oauth, json:true}, function (e, r, body)  {
    req_data = querystring.parse(body);
    token = querystring.stringify({oauth_token: req_data.oauth_token});

 var uri = 'http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/authorize?'+ token; // trying to direct user to this uri

 });
});
```

you must create another function with the same route that will make redirect. So - after you've done with your function just call "next()" at the end of your first ('/') route and make redirect in second one

Comment: Please see the amended code above, is this what you mean?

Comment: simply , if you want to redirect from your function just add this 
|||
response.writeHead(302, {
  'Location': 'your/404/path.html'
  //add other headers here...
});
response.end();

Comment: sorry this is slightly vague for me, can you show me in your example please?